# How to fix issue with import and reload

Tags: python, tkinter, python-importlib

I have a basic tool with a Tkinter GUI that loops through a line test and then allows to do a test on a new service through a separate testing module. I had an issue with the retest just giving the same data as the previous so added importlib.reload(test) which solved that problem, but now the code runs through twice.

I have tried adding a counter like this

```
if n = 0:
   import(test)
   n=n+1
else: 
    reload(test)
```

but on the second loop I get error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test' referenced before assignment

and

```
n = 1
import test as n
n=n+1
```

but then n is no longer a variable.

I need the test to run through once and then reload on the second test with fresh data

Comment: Do you mean you want to load test1 once and run, then load test2 once and run it? Each with their corresponding data?  Or did you mean you want to run a single test with data1, then run that test again with data2?

Comment: OK, I think you meant run a single test twice, each with data 1 and data2.  Which one is your module?  test.py or data1.py and data2.py?  Are these in your project's path?

Comment: Yeah single test with data1 and data2. Test is called from Tkinter GUI and data1 and data2 are stored in a seperate module that is called after it is collected by test using selenium

Answer (score 0):

The first file is **mytestmain.py**.  It calls a **test** function inside a separate module **mytest.py**.

```
# Load file mytest.py from the working directory.
# The calling file is "mytestmain.py", also in the working directory.

import mytest
print(mytest)
# output example: <module 'mytest' from 'c:\\python\\so\\mytest.py'>

data1 = 2
answer1 = 4 

data2 = 3
answer2 = 10 

# Call function "test" inside "mytest.py" module.
# Function "test" calculates a square of a number.

# Test1 with data1=2. Test answer1 is 4.
# This is the correct answer, test should pass.
result = mytest.test(data1, answer1)
print("Result1: ", result)

# Test2 with data2=3.  Test answer2 is 10.
# This is the wrong answer, test should fail.
result = mytest.test(data2, answer2)
print("Result2: ", result)
```

The second file is **mytest.py**, which has the **test** function.  This file is loaded only once.

```
# testing module, named mytest.py

def test(data, answer):
    if data:
        # If data exists, compare with answer.
        if answer == data * data:
            return "Pass"
        else:
            return "Fail"  

# Call test function.
# result = test(2, 4)
# print(result)            

# result = test(3, 10)
# print(result)
```

Reload is only needed when you change a parameter inside the **mytest.py** file.  For testing, the usual workflow is to pass new parameters into the testing file, and not try to change those parameters from inside the test file.  I see reload being using often in Jupyter notebooks, where people are trying out various parameters in one large project that are split into multiple notebooks.  The separate notebooks are not serving a different function.  They are split out to make each file shorter, but all the files are one unit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Tkinter is using "def level", so error local variable 'test' referenced before assignment

Therefore, "global" should fix the issue

```
if n = 0:
   global test
   import(test)
   n=n+1
else: 
   reload(test)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).